# Evaluate bash expression in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying read application version from a file `VERSION` such that `echo -n 1.0.0 > VERSION`, and store the version number in an environment variable, lets say, `VERSION`. My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM debian
WORKDIR /app
COPY VERSION .
ENV VERSION $(cat VERSION)
# I'd like to use the version number in later steps like
RUN apt update && apt install -y curl
RUN curl path/to/executable-${VERSION}
```

`env | grep VERSION` returns:

```
VERSION=$(cat VERSION)
```

I want

```
VERSION=1.0.0
```

Comment: you can not set value for ENV using subshell as it key pair only, but you can try suggested answer. or if you still want from file then try something like `RUN curl path/to/executable-$(cat VERSION)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ENV does not interpolate variables.

How about this:

```
FROM debian
WORKDIR /app
COPY VERSION version-file
RUN echo "export VERSION=$(cat version-file)" >> /root/.bashrc
RUN apt update && apt install -y curl
RUN curl path/to/executable-${VERSION}
```

This uses a RUN step to add an export command to .bashrc file. the export command adds the VERSION env var.

Comment: looks like an easy workaround for my case. build-arg seems a better option though

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the version number as a build argument

```
FROM debian
ARG VERSION
WORKDIR /app
ENV VERSION=$VERSION
# I'd like to use the version number in later steps like
RUN apt update && apt install -y curl
RUN curl path/to/executable-${VERSION}
```

Then you can build it with:

```
docker build --build-arg $VERSION .
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. CI tool builds the image. I'll see if I can pass as argument.

Comment: which CI tool are you using?

Comment: concourse registry-image resource. github.com/vito/oci-build-task. It takes  BUILD_ARG